# Restoration of outdated config server

Tags: mongodb, config

We have 1 test mongodb cluster that includes

- 1 mongos servers
- 3 config servers
- 6 shards

**Q1.** We have tried to restore a outdated config server backup.  We can only find that the config.chunks have less records than before but we can query and insert/update data in the mongodb.  What will be the worst result if we use an outdated config server backup ?

**Q2.** Is there any tools that can re-build the loss records in config server with the existing data in each shard ?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to Q1

With outdated config server contents, iirc, there may be an unnoticed gigantic loss of data. Here is why:

Sharding in MongoDB is based on key ranges. That is, each shard is assigned a range of the shard keys it is responsible for.

For illustration purposes, let's assume you have a shard key of integer numbers starting from 1 to infinity. So the key ranges *could* look like this (exclusive the boundaries)

```
shard0001: -infinity to 100
shard0002: 101 - 200
shard0003: 201 - 300
shard0004: 301 - 400
shard0005: 401 - 500
shard0006: 501 - 600
```

So how does you mongo know about this distribution? It is stored on the config servers. Now let's assume that your metadata has changed and your shard0002 actually holds the data from 100-500. Let's assume you want to retrieve the document with the shard key 450. According to the old metadata, this document has to be on shard0005, if it exists. So the query gets routed to shard0005. An index lookup will be done and the shard finds out that it does not have the document. So while the document exists (on shard0002), due to the outdated metadata it will be looked up on shard0005, where it does not exist.

## Answer to Q2

Not as far as I know. What you could do, however is to use the following procedure for MongoDB < 3.0.0.

> **Disclaimer**
>
> I haven't tested this procedure. Make sure you have the backups ready before wiping the data directories and do not omit the `--repair` and  `--objcheck` flags
>   For maximum security, create filesystem snapshots before using it.
>   If you don't, please do not blame me for any data loss.

1. Shut down the whole cluster *gracefully*
2. Use [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) against the data directory

   ```
    mongodump --repair --dbpath /path/to/your/datafiles -o /path/for/backups/mongo
   ```

   Do this once for each shard.
3. Wipe *all* data directories and recreate your sharded cluster
4. Connect to a `mongos`

   ```
    sh.enableSharding({"database":yourDb})
    sh.shardCollection("yourdDb.yourShardedCollection",{"yourShardKey":1})
   ```
5. From each shard, use [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to write the backups to a mongos

   ```
    mongorestore -h mongosHost:mongosPort --db yourDb --dir /path/for/backups/ \
    --objcheck --write-concern "{w:1}"
   ```

Note that you should *NOT* do the restores in parallel, since this might well overload the balancer.

What we basically do is to gather all data from the individual shards, create a new sharded collection within a new database and put the collected data into that database, with the sharded collection being automatically balanced.

Watch the process very carefully and make absolutely positively sure that you do not overload the balancer, otherwise you might run out of disk space on a shard in case you do not have an optimal shard key.

Of course, you can recreate other sharded databases from the backup by using mongorestore accordingly. To restore unsharded databases, simply connect to the replicaset you want to hold the collection instead of connecting to mongos.

## Side note:

If you need to restore a config server, simply dump one of the other two and restore the config database to that server.

The reason this works is because the metadata can not be updated unless all config servers are up, running and in sync.

Comment: For Q1, we are using tag-aware sharding so that the min / max value of each shard had already been pre-allocated.  As a result, if the value for query or update is still in the min / max range of each shard, it should be able to get data in  correct shard.  However, we are more worried about the mongodb out-of-service if we restore a outdated config server backup, especially some unexpected fault that affect the normal operations of the mongodb cluster

Comment: For Q2, usually some production cluster may have a few terabytes of data, a complete restoration of all data may take days of time and so make production system become unavailable for a few days.  May I know if we have a way to submit a request to mongodb company and let them to consider if it is worth to develop a tool to synchronize the data between config and data server and recover the unmatched data

Comment: For Q1: given the key range for each shard did not change and your tags equal the preassigned key ranges, only chunk splits would not be reflected in the metadata. While this isn't ideal for later scaling, it should not hurt.

Comment: See For Q2: Feel free to open a feature request ticket. However, I doubt that it will be accepted. First of all, to be precise, you would have to lock the database anyway, causing massive downtime you want to prevent. Second, there is [an easy procedure](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-metadata/) to back up the metadata, taking only seconds if automated and sufficient to keep the metadata in a consistent state. Third: you almost never need to restore an outdated backup of the metadata. If you do, two out of three config servers were corrupted. That's an edge case